# How to avoid for loop in numpy

Tags: numpy

How can I avoid the for loop in this numpy operation and create one single array as output that looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
c=(np.random.rand(12,5)*12).round()
for n in np.arange(12):
    print (np.sum(c==n, axis=1))
```

It's important that everything stays in numpy as speed is of great importance.

Comment: How is the `print` command in the loop related to the single array you want as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the for loop by bringing the [0..12[ range into a shape that broadcasts to the correct output:

```
import numpy as np

c = (np.random.rand(12, 5) * 12).round()

a = np.arange(12).reshape(12, 1, 1)
out = np.sum(c==a, axis=-1)
print(out)
```

Note that `c==a` creates a temporary boolean array of shape `(12, 12, 5)`. Keep this in mind if memory is an issue.

Comment: That is correct, but it seems I made a mistake in asking the question. The top left element of the result should tell me how many times a '0' occurs in row 0. The bottom right should show many how many '11' there are in the last row. Any suggestions what I need to change?

Comment: I've restated the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602484/numpy-broadcasting

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
import numpy as np
c = (np.random.rand(12 ,5) * 12).round()
arange_nd = np.empty((12, 12, 5))
for i in range(12):
    arange_nd[i] = np.ones((12, 5)) * i
output = (c == arange_nd).sum(axis=2)
```

the array `output` is your printed result

For loop is only in the creation of the array `arange_nd` and not on the computation.